# Snapshot and artifacts

Tags: maven

I am new to build process.

Can you give me the details about Snapshot and artifacts.

Comment: First i wanted to know how artifacts and snapshot will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best source remains the **[Sonatype books on Maven](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/)** (and on their product Nexus ;) See also [their list of other resources](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/resources/resources-book-links-and-downloads/))

For instance:[Release and Snapshot Repositories](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.9/reference/repoman-sect-repo.html#_release_and_snapshot_repositories)

> A repository stores two types of artifacts: releases and snapshots.
>
> - Release repositories are for stable, static release artifacts.
> - Snapshot repositories are frequently updated repositories that store binary software artifacts from projects under constant development.

Comment: Although this is closed, I was expecting the links in the answer to be valid but they are not. They both end up to a 404 - Not Found page.

Comment: @user3320018 Thank you for pointing out those 4 years-old obsolete links. I have restored them.